# Getting adresses of webpages IP windows prompt

Tags: windows, prompt

I have to compapare if link exist in database already.
I have list of new or existing already websites in txt.file
I wanted to do it by PINGing websites from database, + ping new and compare ip adresses.
txt ipnut:

```
google.com
yahoo.com
example.com
...
```

txt output:

```
    google.com;[ip adress]
    yahoo.com;[ip adress]
    example.com;[ip adress]
    ...
```

i have code which works only partially, i just want to get this adress from @Pinging example.com [**193.138.15.20**] and write it to file like now
:
adress = company name
adress ? 
If you have some better solution in powershell please tell me. thanks

```
@ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL enableextensions
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("d:\companies.txt") do (
      set "_found="
      for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%G in ('ping -4 -n 1 %%i^|findstr /i "TTL="') do (
        echo %%G = %%i
        set "_found=%%G"
      )
      if not defined _found (
        for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%G in ('ping -4 -n 1 %%i^|findstr /ib "Pinging"') do (
          echo %%G ? %%i
          rem set "_found=%%G"
        )
      )
    )>>d:\NOWY.txt
```

Comment: This wouldn't be reliable anyway... you can ping an IP address indeed, but pingged server might just stay silent to ping for security reasons. Also, your logic has a big flaw : a single domain name can be linked to many IP addresses...

Comment: thanks,  I dont have too much experience in networks, i just checked that this solution works for some websites and did not realise that there is a problem. So i should only compare the 'core' of website link?

Comment: It is actually not clear to me which is the desired output and what is the current input (what's in that txt file ?)